# Display single row of each recordset of a column with condtion

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query in SQL Server.

There is a temporary table #final as shown below

[image]

I want to fetch only single row of each project having Maximum EXPECTEDENDDATE.

Comment: Have you tried any query?

Comment: Yes but I am getting a record of only one project I want to display all Project records & here particular condition is that for "Praetorian Track Off" project EXPECTEDSTARTDATE is repeated so just it should display a single record of this having highest EXPECTEDENDDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below one :-

```
Select  f1.*
From    #Final As f1 With (Nolock)
        Join
        (
            Select   Max(EXPECTEDENDDATE) As EXPECTEDENDDATE
                    ,EmployeeCode
                    ,ProjectCode
            From    #Final As t With (Nolock)
            Group By t.EmployeeCode
                     ,t.ProjectCode
        ) As f On f1.EmployeeCode = f.EmployeeCode
                And f1.ProjectCode = f.ProjectCode
                ANd f1.EXPECTEDENDDATE = f.EXPECTEDENDDATE
```

**Update**

```
Declare @final Table
(
     EmployeeCode           Int
    ,ProjectName            Varchar(500)
    ,ExpectedStartDate      Date
    ,ExpectedEndDate        Date
    ,DaysAllocated          Int
)

Declare @SameStartProjects Table
(
     EmployeeCode           Int
    ,ProjectName            Varchar(500)
    ,RowNum                 BigInt
)

Insert Into @final(EmployeeCode,ProjectName,ExpectedStartDate,ExpectedEndDate,DaysAllocated) Values
 (1149,'INT-Vibrant Web','2015-04-22','2015-05-21',14)
,(1149,'INT-Vibrant Web','2015-05-22','2015-05-31',6)
,(1149,'Praetorian Track Off','2015-03-19','2015-05-22',15)
,(1149,'Praetorian Track Off','2015-03-19','2015-06-11',20)
,(1149,'RPost Phase ||','2015-05-01','2015-05-31',20)

Insert Into @SameStartProjects(EmployeeCode,ProjectName,RowNum)
Select   p.EmployeeCode
        ,p.ProjectName
        ,Row_Number() Over(Partition By p.ExpectedStartDate Order By p.ExpectedStartDate) As RowNum
From    @final As p


Select  s.*
From    @final As s
        Join
        (
            Select   f.EmployeeCode
                    ,f.ProjectName
                    ,f.ExpectedStartDate
                    ,Max(f.ExpectedEndDate) As ExpectedEndDate
                    ,Max(sp.RowNum) As RowNum
            From    @final As f
                    Join @SameStartProjects As sp On f.EmployeeCode = sp.EmployeeCode
                            And f.ProjectName = sp.ProjectName
            Group By f.EmployeeCode
                    ,f.ProjectName
                    ,f.ExpectedStartDate
        ) As f On s.EmployeeCode = f.EmployeeCode
            And s.ProjectName = f.ProjectName
            And s.ExpectedEndDate = f.ExpectedEndDate
```

above, @final is your #final table, and i have not taken all the attributes for example

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying.
It is giving me following error message 
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 944
Column '#Final.Employeecode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Oh!, Sorry, put the both attributes in Group By in inner query, like Group By EmployeeCode, ProjectCode

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Here I am getting all Project's single records. I need it only for "Praetorian Track Off" project as it has repeated start date. It only should display single record who has bigger EXPECTEDENDDATE rest all projects should display as it is.

Comment: I am trying to edit it but I am not getting it for generalized form. I have given  here an example but it should be like that for all that projects whose EXPECTEDSTARTDATE is repeated.

Comment: I would just remove EmployeeCode in Subquery  (=> also in group by and in join clause)